# Whether registered AES 256 algorithm in the windows will be used internally by the System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData by default

Tags: .net, cryptography, aes, system.security

if AES 256/256 encryption algorithm is configured in schannel/cipher in the registry in Windows OS then whether AES encryption algorithm will be used internally to encrypt plaintext by the System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData in .net applications?

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData uses DPAPI which since Windows 7 always uses AES256/SHA512 for protecting the stored data.

Comment: Whether there are any documentation to list the default encryption algorithms which are used in different versions of Windows OS.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/51971636/150978